# 49 + 82 = -190? c++ ceasar shift

Tags: c++, char, variable-assignment, calculation

I am working on a code that encrypts messages. First of all, I apply Ceasar shift like this:

```
message[i] += offset;
```

In the case i = 40, offset equals 49 and message[40] equals 82. So 82 += 49 should be 131. (I logged every of the values before and after) Instead of 131, message[40] is now -190.

This is the whole code:

```
string encode(vector<string> rotors, string message, int offset)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++)
    {
        message[i] += offset; // ceasar shift
        while (message[i] > 'Z') message[i] -= 26; // in case the value of the letter is larger than Z go back to the beginning of the alphabet

        for (int j = 0; j < rotors.size(); j++) // the other part of enigma encryption
        {
            message[i] = rotors[j][message[i] - 65];
        }
        offset++; // increase ceasar shift
    }
    return message;
}
```

rotors is a vector of randomized alphabets, message a string that is not more than 50 chars and offset an integer for the ceasar shift (in case this is important).

So my question is:
Why does it make -190 out of 82 + 49? This occurs not only on my PC but also on online compilers.

EDIT: This only applys to this special case where i = 40 and offset = 49. In all other cases (larger or smaller) it works as expected.

In case you want to reproduce this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

string encode(vector<string> rotors, string message, int offset) {
    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        message[i] += offset;
        while (message[i] > 'Z') message[i] -= 26;
        for (int j = 0; j < rotors.size(); j++) {
            message[i] = rotors[j][message[i] - 65];
        }
        offset++;
    }
    return message;
}

int main()
{
    string message;
    int pseudoRandomNumber;
    vector<string> rotors;
    cin >> pseudoRandomNumber; cin.ignore();

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        string rotor;
        getline(cin, rotor);
        rotors.push_back(rotor);
    }
    getline(cin, message);

    message = decode(rotors, message, pseudoRandomNumber);

    cout << message << endl;
}
```

Copy this and give it this as input:

```
9
BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO
AJDKSIRUXBLHWTMCQGZNPYFVOE
EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ
EVERYONEISWELCOMEHEREEVERYONEISWELCOMEHERE
```

Comment: "special case" indicates that you have memory corruption/undefined behavior/[nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). Can you show a [mre] that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce your results?

Comment: Signed arithmetic overflow, leading to *undefined behavior*. It's implementation defined if plain `char` is signed or unsigned. In your case it seems to be a signed type.

Comment: `std::string` uses `char` elements. `char` without an explicit `signed` or `unsigned` attached to it will be *either* signed or unsigned depending on the compiler implementation. In your case, `char` is clearly signed, which means it has a valid range of `-128..127`, and `131` is outside of that range, so you are encountering integer overflow.

Comment: And note that even if you make all characters explicitly unsigned (including the ones in the strings), you still have a problem that the result might not be printable, if that's your goal.

Comment: Is `message[40]` -190 or is it -125 (82 + 49 when stored as an 8-bit twos-complement signed number), where the -190 comes from -125 - 65 (after promoting `message[i]` from char to int before the subtraction)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the type `char` behaves as the type signed char then the minimum and maximum values that can be stored in an object of the type can be obtained the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << static_cast<int>( std::numeric_limits<char>::min() ) << '\n';
    std::cout << static_cast<int>( std::numeric_limits<char>::max() ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
-128
127
```

That is an object of the type `char` is unable to store the value `131`.

If to output the value `131` in hex

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << 131 << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

then you will get

```
0x83
```

that in binary looks like

```
10000011
```

As it is seen the sign bit is set

```
10000011`
^
```

So this value stored in an object of the type `char` represents a negative number.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, for signed integer types.

Comment: Overflow only exists for signed integer types. Like the `char` in question. Thus, I wondered if it changed or why nobody mentioned it.